# How to Identify the existing SharePoint 2013 site collection is Team site OR Publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have one site collection created by some other Resource. Now I need to know the whether "**existing site is Team site or publishing site**" how to Identify this could you please help on this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to identify whether site is team site or publishing

1. Browse to any page on the site, view the source HTML of the page, then search for “SiteTemplateID” where you will be taken straight to a line of JavaScript embedded into the page such as the following where the site template ID including configuration is assigned to a JavaScript variable:

   ```
   var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = ‘STS#1′;
   ```
2. The easiest way is to get a tool like [SharePoint Manager.](http://www.codeplex.com/spm) Go into the site you are looking at, and find the WebTemplateId property. You can then match it up to a list of known template types.
3. Using SP Object Model we can identify

   ```
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
   {   
      string templateID = web.WebTemplateId.ToString();
   }
   ```
4. Using STSADM.EXE: It needs high level permissions. Means the user should be an administrator on the server. Below is the command we need to use for knowing the site template.

   ```
   stsadm.exe -o enumallwebs -database [content database name]
   ```